# Cannot click an icon within a div. Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, automation, krypton

code cannot find this icon wherein i have to click it i just notice that it is within a div. here is my sample code:

```
findLink(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Dashlet Actions' and contains(@ng-click,'updateActionMenu')]")).click
```

please see image for further information

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the desired element you can use the following solution:

- `css`:

  ```
  findLink(By.css("button.btn.btn-link[aria-label='Dashlet Actions']")).click
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  findLink(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-link' and @aria-label='Dashlet Actions']")).click
  ```

**Note**: The element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so you have to induce [ExplicitWait](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) for the desired *element to be clickable*

Comment: error still ocurrs that the WaituntilPresent" in console. meaning it cannot find the element

Comment: Check out my answer update and let me know the status

Comment: it now works!! thanks! just have to use by.cssSelector rather than cs. a big thanks!!!

Comment: would like to ask if there is a possibility for a screenshot script in selenium?

Comment: Of coarse it is possible to rite a screenshot script. But as it would be a different topic you may need to raise a new question with your new requirement. StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Use css selector to click.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-link")).click();
```

Comment: It's working! but the class btn btn-link is not unique is it possible to use the aria-label tag for it using CSS Selector?